# Is it possible to assign default value to a variable in case the first value doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, default-value

for example I think of a situation like this:

```
string param1 (argv[i+1]);
```

and I know that it is possible that this may look out of array length, is there a way to declare in a program that whenever I put statement like this a default value will be assigned, something like obviously incorrect string param1 (argv[i+1] or "default");

Comment: There's no way for the compiler to know that `i + 1` is not a valid array index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
string param1((i < argc-1) ? argv[i+1] : "default");
```

Answer (score 2):

Um, well, the obvious.

```
char const * avi1 = "default";
if (argc > (i + 1)) {
    avi1 = argv[i+1];
}
string param1(avi1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

If you know that this may look outside of array length, check it manually.Something like

```
string param1((i < argc-1) ? argv[i+1] : "default");
```